# R cbind with get paste

Tags: r, get, paste, cbind

`cbind()` function works as `x <- cbind(a,b)`

where column name 'b' can be specified for the function `b = get(paste0('var',i))`,

that is `x <- cbind(a,b = get(paste0('var',i)))`

I am trying to do the following:

`x <- cbind(a, get(paste0('var',i))) = j)`, where "j" can be a vector or a function.

however, got the following error: `Error: unexpected '=' in "x <- cbind(a, get(paste0('var',i))) = j)"`

If i just specify `"x <- cbind(a, get(paste0('var',i))))"`, then the 2nd column name is `"get(paste0('var',i))))"`, which is not convenient.

How can I define column names with a function `get(paste())` within `cbind()` or `rbind()` or `bind_cols()`? Or what would be the alternative solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An example would have been helpful to understand the problem but maybe this?

```
x <- cbind(a, j)
colnames(x)[2] <- get(paste0('var',i))
```

Or if you want to do it in single line -

```
x <- cbind(a, setNames(j, get(paste0('var',i))))
```

Comment: That would work, but in my case the 'j' is dynamic vector, therefore, it is the same problem.

Comment: Can you provide an example?

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot, because I work on the remote server with a set of many csv files. The point is: I would like to make a new calculated variable (column) for each of the data frames, that is conditional on dataframe name, and bind it to each data frame, therefore, I am trying to 'paste' the specific name to the cbind() function.

Comment: So far came with this solution: `assign('a', function())` 
`assign('b', function())` 
`X <- cbind(a, b)` 
`colnames(x)[ncol(x)] <- paste0('var',i)` 
`assign(paste0('x',i), x)`

Answer (score 0):

We can use

```
x <- data.frame(a, j)
colnames(x)[2] <- get(paste('var', i, sep=""))
```

---

Or use `tibble`

```
tibble(a, !! b := j)
```